# Using the first column of a file as input in a script

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I am having some problems with using the first column ${1} as input to a script.

Currently the portions of the script looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="${1}"
for NAME in `cat ${INPUT}`
do
    SIZE="`du -sm /FAServer/na3250-a/homes/${NAME} | sed 's|/FAServer/na3250-a/homes/||'`"
    DATESTAMP=`ls -ld /FAServer/na3250-a/homes/${NAME} | awk '{print $6}'`
echo "${SIZE} ${DATESTAMP}"
done
```

However, I want to modify the INPUT="${1}" to take the first {1} within a specific file. This is so I can run the lines above in another script and use a file that is previously generated as the input. Also to have the output go out to a new file.

So something like:

```
INPUT="$location/DisabledActiveHome ${1}"   ???
```

Here's my full script below.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will search through Disabled Users OU and compare that list of
# names against the current active Home directories. This is to find out
# how much space those Home directories take up and which need to be removed.

# MUST BE RUN AS SUDO!

# Setting variables for _adm and storage path.

echo "Please provide your _adm account name:"
read _adm
echo "Please state where you want the files to be generated: (absolute path)"
read location

# String of commands to lookup information using ldapsearch

ldapsearch -x -LLL -h "REDACTED" -D $_adm@"REDACTED" -W -b "OU=Accounts,OU=Disabled_Objects,DC="XX",DC="XX",DC="XX"" "cn=*" | grep 'sAMAccountName'| egrep -v '_adm$' | cut -d' ' -f2 > $location/DisabledHome

# Get a list of all the active Home directories

ls /FAServer/na3250-a/homes > $location/ActiveHome

# Compare the Disabled accounts against Active Home directories

grep -o -f $location/DisabledHome $location/ActiveHome > $location/DisabledActiveHome

# Now get the size and datestamp for the disabled folders

INPUT="${1}"
for NAME in `cat ${INPUT}`
do
    SIZE="`du -sm /FAServer/na3250-a/homes/${NAME} | sed 's|/FAServer/na3250-a/homes/||'`"
    DATESTAMP=`ls -ld /FAServer/na3250-a/homes/${NAME} | awk '{print $6}'`
echo "${SIZE} ${DATESTAMP}"
done
```

I'm new to all of this so any help is welcome. I will be happy to clarify any and all questions you might have.

EDIT: A little more explanation because I'm terrible at these things.

The lines of code below came from a previous script are a FOR loop:

```
INPUT="${1}"
    for NAME in `cat ${INPUT}`
    do
        SIZE="`du -sm /FAServer/na3250-a/homes/${NAME} | sed 's|/FAServer/na3250-a/homes/||'`"
        DATESTAMP=`ls -ld /FAServer/na3250-a/homes/${NAME} | awk '{print $6}'`
    echo "${SIZE} ${DATESTAMP}"
    done
```

It is executed by typing:

```
./Script ./file
```

The FILE that is being referenced has one column of user names and no other data:

```
User1
User2
User3
etc.
```

The Script would take the file and look at the first users name, which is reference by

```
INPUT=${1}
```

then run a DU command on that user and find out what the size of their HOME drive is. That would be reported by the SIZE variable. It will do the same thing with the DATESTAMP in regards to when the HOME drive was created for the user. When it is done doing the tasks for that user, it would move on to the next one in the column until it is done.

So following that logic, I want to automate the entire process. Instead of doing this in two steps, I would like to make this all a one step process.

The first process would be to generate the $location/DisabledActiveHome file, which would have all of the disabled users names. Then to run the last portion to get the Size and creation date of each HOME drive for all the users in the DisabledActiveHome file.

So to do that, I need to modify the

```
INPUT=${1}
```

line to reflect the previously generated file.

```
$location/DisabledActiveHome
```

Comment: So how about `INPUT="$location/DisabledActiveHome"`?

Comment: I thought about it, but I don't have enough knowledge to figure out the difference between {1} and the actual path to the file.

Is it the same thing? Will the results really be similar?

I ran a test and got a lot more blank lines between usernames with the directory path than {1} argument tag.

Comment: INPUT="$location/DisabledActiveHome" worked like a charm. I was confused about the syntax and the proper usage and output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question really, but I think you want this. Say your file is called `file.txt` and looks like this:

```
1 99
2 98
3 97
4 96
```

You can get the first column like this:

```
awk '{print $1}' file.txt
1
2
3
4
```

If you want to use that in your script, do this

```
while read NAME; do  
   echo $NAME
done < <(awk '{print $1}' file.txt)
1
2
3
4
```

Or you may prefer `cut` like this:

```
while read NAME; do  
  echo $NAME
done < <(cut -d" " -f1 file.txt)
1
2
3
4
```

Or this may suit even better

```
while read NAME OtherUnwantedJunk; do
   echo $NAME
done < file.txt
1
2
3
4
```

This last, and probably best, solution above uses `IFS`, which is `bash`'s Input Field Separator, so if your file looked like this

```
1:99
2:98
3:97
4:96
```

you would do this

```
while IFS=":" read NAME OtherUnwantedJunk; do
   echo $NAME
done < file.txt
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good at explaining things. Let me try and clarify what I mean.
I want to modify the "INPUT=${1}" to reflect the file that is generated in the lines above, which is located in "$location/DisabledActiveHome". However, I want to reference not just that file, but the first column in that file.

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what you mean. Please make your question FAR simpler and show how the files look before and after your script - else I don't think you will get an answer.

Comment: So previously, the "INPUT=${1}" portion of the script is copied from another script that was executed along side with a reference file. 
Example:   ./InputScript ./ReferenceFile
So the INPUT=${1} would just take the first input of each container in the ReferenceFile.

What I am trying to do is use that same concept in one script instead of having to run the tasks separately.

So instead instead of INPUT={1}, I would like it to take the first column from the "$location/DisabledActiveHome" file.

Does that clear it up a little more?

Comment: BTW, the $location/DisabledActiveHome file looks like one long column with user names. That's it, no other data in it.

user1
user2
user3
etc.

Comment: Not really:-( It would be better to click `edit` under your question and make truly represent what you are asking where it is properly formatted and intelligible to all.

Comment: Let me do that. Hang on.

Comment: Just made a big edit to my original post. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

`INPUT="$location/DisabledActiveHome"` worked like a charm. I was confused about the syntax and the proper usage and output